# EF core changes primary key columns depending on the property name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ef-core-7.0

I'm aware about some **conventions** of **EF core**, such as when naming a property `"Id"`.

But this one is really strange. I'm dealing with a legacy database where I'm now at least renaming the properties, but not yet the columns themselves:

```
[Column("OtherEntityNr")]
public long? OtherEntityNr { get; set; }
```

I changed to:

```
[Column("OtherEntityNr")]
public long? OtherEntityId { get; set; }   // <----- replaced "Nr" with "Id"
```

This change lead to a migration being created that changed `nullable` to `false`. However, this is not the case, as you see the column is a `long?` FK.

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
    name: "OtherEntityNr",
    table: "OtherEntity",
    type: "bigint",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0L,
    oldClrType: typeof(long),
    oldType: "bigint",
    oldNullable: true);
```

**Question:** How can I change the column name without triggering EF to create logical changes based on naming conventions?

Comment: Have you added the Key/PrimaryKey attribute on the property that matches the actual primary key? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key

Comment: Yes. It's a composite primary key, actually.

Comment: Can you share the entire class?

Comment: The migration is correct. If the column is part of a PK, it can't be NULL, no matter what the property says. Why is the property ` long?` in the first place? What's the actual table schema? Is `OtherEntityNr` the primary key or not?

Comment: The column is a FK, not PK. Sorry for writing it the wrong way. It's a composite FK with a composite PK in another table.